Explicitly understanding forms vs densities on a Moebius strip
I encountered a post John Baez made on some old Usenet thread in which he talked about how in order to integrate things on a non-orientable manifold you need pseudoforms/densities rather than forms, and he talked specifically about how you could discover this by looking at how you would integrate on a Moebius strip, by cutting it up etc.
I decided to try and define integration on a Moebius strip as explicitly and simply as I could. Instead of making two charts to completely cover it, I just made a single cut, and ignored that line. Instead, I will just impose conditions on the functions I try to integrate.
The strip is parameterized by $(x,y)$ which both run from -1 to 1. Now if we want it to be a Moebius strip, we need every function $f(x,y)$ on it to obey:
$$f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$$
I integrate using the obvious form $dxdy$. My understanding is that the only difference in this case between a differential form and a density is that if, say, I made the change of variables $(x,y)\to (-x,y)$, then the form would be multiplied by -1, whereas the density would be multiplied by the absolute value of the determinant, therefore +1. But the way I set up this problem, I can do the following integral just fine thinking about forms:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1} dx dy f(x,y) $$
In fact it predictably fails to make sense if I don't multiply by -1 when I change variables. So obviously what I'm doing is not the right way to go about showing why you need densities, but then what is the right way?

The point of defining densities is that you can work with intrinsically defined concepts that are independent of either choosing coordinates or choosing a fundamental domain.  You can always choose a fundamental domain and an orientation on it, which would seem to obviate the need for densities if you are willing to make such choices, as you did above.

Could you perhaps demonstrate how I would go about doing it with densities, and what goes wrong if I try to do it with forms?

The problem is quite simple: there is no volume form on a non-orientable manifold.  So the whole machinery with $\Omega^n(M)$ does not apply :-)  So what goes wrong is the first step.

Huh alright... What about the density then? I'm just trying to figure out in what sense the density transforms by the absolute value of the determinant, in this particular circumstance.

Think of density as giving the unsigned area (therefore always nonnegative), whereas a form gives the signed area.  Since the density is always nonnegative, it can't transform by the determinant, and must transform by its absolute value
